# Visual Studio 2008 Class Diagram designer

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using VS class diagram designer. How can I get the blue lines as that in the following image? Thanks!

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa288743.clssdsgnr-fig01big%28en-us,VS.71%29.gif))</sub>

Comment: Please re-insert the link. the last part of the url is not in the href of the link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to right click on properties and select show as association or show as collection association, as in each property in your class object which has an association can have this view where you can physically see the association between objects. Just a different view.

Andrew

Comment: Okay, thanks!

If I wanna to link a method to a class, what should I do?

Comment: You can alter your diagram so that the full method signature shows on the method.